# MySQL: item count not same as selected items

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, shop and categories:

```
shop as s    categories as c
---------    ----------------
-itemId      -itemId
-itemName    -categoryId
-...
```

The following query returns the correct items, which are belonging to category 1 and 11 (in my test case 4 items were returned):

```
SELECT s.itemId, s.*
FROM shop AS s
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON s.itemId = c.itemId
WHERE ( c.categoryId = 1 OR c.categoryId = 11)
GROUP BY s.itemId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.categoryId) = 2
```

Now I wanted to count the items with the following query...

```
COUNT(s.itemId)
FROM shop AS s
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON s.itemId = c.itemId
WHERE ( c.categoryId = 1 OR c.categoryId = 11)
GROUP BY s.itemId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.categoryId) = 2
```

... but the query returns 2, the number of categories, and not 4, the number of items.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `IN` query to do the count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM shop
WHERE itemId IN (
    SELECT s.itemId
    FROM shop AS s
    INNER JOIN categories AS c ON s.itemId = c.itemId
    WHERE c.categoryId IN (1, 11)
    GROUP BY s.itemId
    HAVING MIN(c.categoryId) <> MAX(c.categoryId)
);
```

Note that your first query appears in the above subquery, to identify the matching items.